# Is the velocity of a fluid in a vertical tube constant?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow, bernoulli-equation

Here is how I concluded that:

Let there be two points $A$ and $B$ in a tube, $B$ being a little higher up.
Using the *Bernoulli's equation*:

> $$P_B+\frac{\rho v'^2}{2}+\rho gh=(\rho gh+P_B)+\frac{\rho v^2}{2}$$

Here, the terms cancel and the velocity comes to be equal.

Have I made an incorrect assumption?

According to other answers this is not true .

Comment: Is the pressure in $B$ actually equal to the pressure in $A$? And what about the height of points $A$ and $B$ as you stated that the tube is vertical? If the answer to both questions is "no", then these differences should be considered and then $v\neq v'$.

Comment: How come the height of the points are same? Didn't you mention that _the point $B$ is a little higher than point $A$_?

Comment: @lee I have included height term in the LHS the term in the bracket is the hydrostatic pressure due to the weight of the water above it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the vertical pipe is of *constant cross-section*, and because Bernoulli applies to incompressible fluids only, then the continuity equation tells us:

$$vA=v'A'$$

with $A=A'$, then:

$$v=v'$$

applies always.

You may be confused by the following situation:

[image: Bernoulli]

Here, because the top reservoir is very large, then $v_0\approx 0$ and $v_1$ can then be calculated from Bernoulli ($v_1\approx \sqrt{2gh}$ with $h$ the length of the pipe)

Then $v_1\gg v_0$.

But the velocity **inside the pipe** is always the same, that is $v_1$, for the reason outlined higher up. And $v_0$ lays of course outside the tube.

Comment: Very interesting so the water does not speed up due to gravity when falling through the tube ?

Comment: It does speed up due to gravity but the velocity anywhere in the tube is the same, as long as the column of water in the tube is continuous and unbroken.

Comment: Are you saying the water column as a whole speeds up ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Each water particle is in free fall in a central gravitational field. If we assume the pressure on the reservoir to be $P_0$, the pressure on the tube opening to be also $P_0$, then the exit velocity is $v_1=\sqrt{2gh}$ where $h$ is the length of the tube. This is of course the formula for an object in free fall with no friction or drag.

Comment: Sorry for going back to square one again but if this is comparable to free fall then won't the water particles near the exit be faster then the particles that have not exited ? So how can the velocity be uniform ? Thanks for your patience sir.

Comment: If the water column 'breaks' the lower particles would be traveling (falling) faster than the higher ones. We've specified that doesn't happen. Such a column could break if it was wide and slow.

Comment: Ah yes sir ! Thanks alot .

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.